# WPF:stretch to parent loop

Tags: wpf, xaml

In my WPF application I am trying to connect all the sizes to the app size. So the main grid stretches to the main window, the canvas - to the main grid etc. But this does not work. For example, ScrollViewer that is inside of the canvas, stretches to the main grid.
What is a solution?
Simple code for example:

```
<Window Height="400" Width="200" ...>
 <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Canvas Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <ScrollViewer   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">

        </ScrollViewer>
    </Canvas>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the canvas and it will work.

Basically, canvas has infinite size by default, so everything in canvas cannot be aligned, unless you specify size maually.

```
<Window Height="400" Width="200" ...>
  <Grid>
    <ScrollViewer>

     </ScrollViewer>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

Note, that you dont have to specify Grid's Column and Row Definitions, if there's only single cell. it works by default. Also, Horizontal and Vertical Alignment hav value "Stretch" by default, so it does not have to be specified explicitelly as well.

Since there is nothing but scrollviewer inside the grid, you could remove the grid as well:

```
<Window Height="400" Width="200" ...>
  <ScrollViewer>             

  </ScrollViewer>
</Window>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Liero, there are things to learn. A problem is that the application is more complicated.  I am using those extra items: in different moments some of them I hide and some of of them I show. So in my case children stretch not to the closest parent, but to the global one.

Comment: Children are always aligned to the closest parent. There's no other option. Canvas breaks stretching of children. In order to enable stretching you need to move children out of canvas, or databound children's Height and Width to ActualHeight resp. ActualWidth of one of the parents.